# CentOS remount a used disk

Tags: centos, nginx, mount, hard-drive, diskmanagement

I have a used disk full of video files which is 1TB in size and is mounted on /usr/local/nginx/html. I want to remount it on /disk1 for naming purposes. If I remount it would the files still be intact? Eg: /usr/local/nginx/html/folder/file.txt be moved to /disk1/folder/file.txt?

Im asking this because Ill be doing it on a production server. I could order a new HDD for this so I could backup>remount>restore but thats not cost effective for me.

Comment: Can you just symlink it?

Answer (score 2):

If the situation is as you describe it, this would indeed be the case. And `nginx` wouldn't find the files anymore....

Beside symlinking, you could also just mount the FS a second time at the new location, possibly with the `--bind` option (see `man mount`).

Answer (score 0):

I agree that a symlink is probably your best shot, you can do this like this:

```
ln -s /usr/local/nginx/html /disk1
```

that way you can reach the drive from both paths.